# what's the counterpart for gl_TexCoord in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I have a OpenGL shader which uses gl_TexCoord like the following does. But in OpenGL ES, gl_TexCoord is not supported. I wonder what can I do to refactor the code to get it work on OpenGL ES.

```
void main() 
{
    //scene depth calculation
    float depth = linearize(texture2D(inputImageTexture2,gl_TexCoord[0].xy).x);
    if (depthblur)
    {
        depth = linearize(bdepth(gl_TexCoord[0].xy));
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't one. You do it manually with a user-defined `varying` passed from your vertex shader. That's all it ever was anyway; a per-vertex output that your fragment shader took.

Comment: got it. further, what's the difference between gl_TexCoord[0] and gl_TexCoord[3]? any article/document that could be referenced to understand that?

Comment: @tom: It's an *array*. That's what the `[]` syntax means in most languages.

Comment: That's for sure. I was trying to understand what's gl_TexCoord[0] and gl_TexCoord[3] are for. In the code that I inherited, it referenced gl_TexCoord[0] and gl_TexCoord[3], but no gl_TexCoord[1] and gl_TexCoord[2], so I was wondering why. Any suggestions?

Comment: @tom: Because that's how it was written. You'd have to ask the original writer of the shader why he picked those two texture coordinate indices.

Comment: Can you post the solution somewhere? Im trying to go from Quartz Composer to iOS and im trying to replace gl_TexCoord[0].st